# Photo backup and management

Tags: itunes, ipad, icloud, photos

I have run out of space on my 16gb iPad . Over 7.2 go are my photos and video. Is it possible to separate my photos and keep most on iCloud or iTunes, accessing only when I wish to review them.  How can I do so if possible.  I need to free up space. Also, any quick way to delete duplicate photos or files?

Answer (score 1):

Mac or PC? It makes a difference.

Recently on the PC my wife was having a similar problem. The phone will sync **everything** in the pictures folder. So I created a sub folder called iPhone and set the sync in iTunes to only sync with that folder and not the whole pictures folder. Now she just has to move the pics she wants on the phone to that folder.

On the Mac (going from memory here, so...) you can actually select which iPhoto albums you sync with the iPad. So instead of **all** photos/videos select only the albums you want/need on the iPad itself.

Make sense?